# Replacing characters in multiple folder and file names

Tags: windows-11, batch-rename, files-folders, plex

I have a large movie library using Plex (Local Media Server) and have named multiple files in the wrong order. Plex will disregard square brackets when searching file names for a corresponding movie.

So, I want to replace brackets "**(**" and "**)**" with square brackets "**[**" and "**]**" - and then vice versa, replace square brackets with normal brackets, at the same time - in multiple folder names and file names.

All folders are named: 
Movie Title - Extended Title If Sequel **[** YEAR **]** **(** RESOLUTION-Can-Differ **)**

I want to rename them: 
Movie Title - Extended Title If Sequel **(** YEAR **)** **[** RESOLUTION-Can-Differ **]**

And the same with the files inside the folders, which have the exact same name as its folder name.

Is this possible to do with script in bulk or would it be easier to do in stages? For example just change every *YEAR* in sq. brackets "[" "]" to "(" ")" and then change the last part seperately.

Also, the folders and files are located on a NAS (Network Storage) which I can access from my Windows 11 PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Powershell to rename the folders and/or files.

1. Open File Explorer. Go to the parent folder. Right-click on a empty area, click on Open Powershell window here.
2. Enter and run the following:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match '(.+)(\[)(.+)(\])(.+)(\()(.+)(\))'} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace '(.+)(\[)(.+)(\])(.+)(\()(.+)(\))','$1$6$3$8$5$2$7$4'}
```

Comment: This worked pretty well. I was able to change hundreds of folders correctly. However, the filenames inside were unchanged. Is there a way to make this also change the file name inside the folders that get renamed? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Pete Try the command again. I have removed some special characters. It should now work with folders and files.

Comment: But using the command now (when my folders are correctly named), wouldn't it change the folders back to the wrong format of for the folders while changing the file name correctly? I.E. right now all my folders are correct: "Movie (Year) [Res]" but the file inside is now still "Movie [Year] (Res)". Any way of matching the file inside to the now correct folder name? If this makes sense?

Comment: @Pete It won't as the regex `(.+)(\[)(.+)(\])(.+)(\()(.+)(\))` is matching the square brackets first, then the "normal" brackets. It only replaces them if the square brackets are found before the normal ones.